# MySQL Conditional ASC/DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure, mariadb

I am trying to create a stored procedure so I can easily sort some data in either ascending or descending order. I have looked all over the internet and finally got **MySQL** to accept what I am trying to do, but now when I call the procedure it produces garbage data. If I run the query on its own, everything works perfectly. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS OrderPlants;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE OrderPlants (IN OrderSeq CHAR(4))

BEGIN

SELECT Location.State, Operator.Name, Plant.TotalOutput
FROM Plant

INNER JOIN Location
ON Plant.LocationID = Location.ID

INNER JOIN Operator
ON Plant.OperatorID = Operator.ID

ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @OrderSeq = 'ASC' THEN Plant.TotalOutput END ASC,
CASE WHEN @OrderSeq = 'DESC' THEN Plant.TotalOutput END DESC

LIMIT 5;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

And here is the output it produces:

```
MariaDB [nuclear]> call orderplants ('ASC');
+-------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| State | Name                        | TotalOutput |
+-------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| FL    | Florida Power & Light Co.   |        6040 |
| IA    | CORN BELT POWER COOP        |          38 |
| KY    | DUKE ENERGY KENTUCKY INC    |         648 |
| IN    | JASPER MUNICIPAL UTIL (IN)  |          15 |
| OH    | FIRSTENERGY GENERATION CORP |          18 |
+-------+-----------------------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

This is what the data should look like if the procedure was called with the **DESC** input:

```
+-------+--------------------------------+-------------+
| State | Name                           | TotalOutput |
+-------+--------------------------------+-------------+
| AZ    | Arizona Public Service Company |       11970 |
| AL    | Tenessee Valley Authority      |       10374 |
| PA    | PPL Susquehanna, LLC           |        7904 |
| TX    | STP Nuclear Operating Co.      |        7706 |
| SC    | Duke Energy Carolinas, LLC     |        7704 |
+-------+--------------------------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And what the output should be with the **ASC** input:

```
+-------+-------------------------------+-------------+
| State | Name                          | TotalOutput |
+-------+-------------------------------+-------------+
| PA    | KOPPERS CO                    |           3 |
| MN    | NORTHERN STATES POWER CO (MN) |           7 |
| MN    | AMERICAN CRYSTAL SUGAR CO     |           8 |
| IA    | MIDAMERICAN ENERGY CO         |           8 |
| IN    | JASPER MUNICIPAL UTIL (IN)    |          15 |
+-------+-------------------------------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: The datatype of totaloutput is INT

Comment: Does it do the same if you call with 'ASC ', meaning a space in the end? Since CHAR(4) means always 4 characters and ASC is only three.

Comment: Perhaps `CASE WHEN OrderSeq = 'ASC'` without `@`

Comment: Removing the @ fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Are either (ASC/DESC) working fine?

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this:

```
ORDER BY if(@OrderSeq = 'ASC', Plant.TotalOutput, -Plant.TotalOutput)
```

here is sample fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60b4e/7

Answer (score 0):

Removing the @ from

```
CASE WHEN @OrderSeq = 'ASC' THEN Plant.TotalOutput END ASC
```

and

```
CASE WHEN @OrderSeq = 'DESC' THEN Plant.TotalOutput END DESC
```

Has solved the problem